# Driver.launch_app() is not launching app in python script

Tags: python, android, automation, appium

Currently starting to work with python and appium automation. I have done some research and gotten started with connecting to a device but after connecting the device my app does not launch. I have the script below:

```
from appium import webdriver

url = 'http://jq.deviceconnect.com/Appium'
caps = {
    'gigafox:UserName': 'admin',
    'gigafox:ApiKey': '####',
    'gigafox:application': 'com.google.android.youtube/com.google.
     android.apps.youtube.app.application.Shell$HomeActivity',
    'newCommandTimeout': 600000,
    'gigafox:device': '58d5251c-89cd-4f7a-b2f1-8f316e292e0b',
    'gigafox:SkipInstall': 'true',
    'automationName': 'UIAutimator2'
}

# Start Appium session
print('creating Appium session')
driver = webdriver.Remote(url, caps)
driver.launch_app()
```

After running this my device has been connected to but then my app does not launch and the build is completed. No error so I assume there is nothing wrong other than how I am implementing it.

Comment: I found using appPackage and appActivity worked when trying to launch the app and not gigafox:application. I am not sure why but I will use this as a workaround until I find out why it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on GigaFox documentation click [here](http://docs.mobilelabsinc.com/GigaFox/GigaFoxDoc/appium.html):

> Upload the app to GigaFox and use the bundleId (iOS) or appPackage and appActivity capabilities, per Appium documentation, to direct launch the app. GigaFox will install the app using its own content storage system and install code, enforcing ACLs as relevant.

More about Appium desired capabilities you can find [here](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/).